# It is known if $n$ is prime for all $n\leq N$

Tags: prime-numbers

This is more of a curiosity than a research question, but I could not find it answered anywhere. What is the largest $N$ for which the statement in the title is true? I have recently read that the largest known prime is $2^{82589933} − 1$, but I imagine it is not known if, for example, $2^{82589933} − 3$ is prime.
A closely related question: if $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function, that is, $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes not exceeding $x$, what is the largest value of $n$ for which $\pi(n)$ is known exactly?

Comment: What is the "statement in the title"?  It currently says "It is known if $n$ is prime for all $n \le N$", which, depending on the quantification, is never to rarely true.

Comment: @LSpice: the meaning is, what is the largest $N$ for which the primeness/compositeness of $n$ is "known" for all $n \leq N$. (I put "known" in quotes because I think it is hard to make this question precise... how could we in any sense "know" all numbers less than $2^{\textrm{large number}}$.)

Comment: I'm assuming the exponent is supposed to be $82589933$. $2^{82589933}-3$ is not prime as it's divisible by $23$.

Comment: @SamHopkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438418/it-is-known-if-n-is-prime-for-all-n-leq-n#comment1130479_438418), ah, that makes more sense.  I was reading "if" in "it is known if $n$ is prime for all $n \le N$" as "that", whereas, as you point out, I should have read it as "whether".

Comment: I suggest a new title: What is the smallest number for which we don't yet know primality?   But since primality testing is polynomial time, the answer may quickly become obsolete.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: yes, the fact that "PRIMES is in P" means the question does not really make sense. It's akin to the old "what's the smallest non-interesting number" chestnut...

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: That's a little like asking, "what is the smallest natural number that has not been used in the public record?"  Valid question, the answer negates the validity of the question, and is there any real interest in having an answer?

Comment: @RyanBudney I agree, and that was my point.

Comment: I corrected the typo: $2^{82589933}−1$ is the largest known prime. A lengthy but hopefully clearer phrasing of my question: "What is the largest $N$ with the property that we can decide if $n$ is or isn't prime, for each $n\leq N$?"

Comment: Valerio, you ask about whether we "can" decide primality for $n\leq N$, but we can decide primality for any number. If you mean to refer to which $N$ have we already done these tests, then if we knew such $N$, we could immediately increase it to $N+1$, and then $N+2$, and so on, for as much as want, since primality testing of any particular number is feasible. (Factoring is difficult; primality testing is easy.)

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins I think I may not have explained clearly enough what I meant. I do not understand how testing primality for any number can be feasible. Surely there will be numbers for which we cannot decide if they are primes or not, because they are too large. Otherwise what is the meaning of the announcement that  $2^{82589933}−1$ is the largest known prime? I am thinking of an experiment, aided by a computer: take $N$, examine al numbers $1\leq n \leq N$ and for each decide if $n$ is prime or not. Surely there will be a largest $N$ for which this is possible, given a current computer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fast_deterministic_tests

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins I am sorry but I am still lost. I understand that there are superfast primality tests, but surely there is a limit. Just like there is a largest known prime with the current state of technology, it seems natural to ask if there a largest $N$ as in my question.

Comment: Related, on MathSE: [What is the largest $n$ for which the $n$th prime is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75233/16397)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, there is no well-defined answer to this question, because there is no organized effort to test primality of all numbers up to a certain bound.

However, there is a (more or less) well-defined answer (at any given point in time) to a related question: What is the largest $N$ for which the primality status of $2^n - 1$ is known for all $n\le N$?  The answer, as of this writing, is [57885161](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/) (though some "insiders" in the GIMPS project may be able to report a slightly higher number than that—but not higher than 74207281).